# select pandas dataframe datetime column based on times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

i have the following dataframe:

```
                    timestamp  mes
0     2019-01-01 18:15:55.700  1228
1     2019-01-01 18:35:56.872  1402
2     2019-01-01 18:35:56.872  1560
3     2019-01-01 19:04:25.700  1541
4     2019-01-01 19:54:23.150  8754
5     2019-01-02 18:01:00.025  4124
6     2019-01-02 18:17:56.125  9736
7     2019-01-02 18:58:59.799  1597
8     2019-01-02 20:10:15.896  5285
```

How can I select only the rows where `timestamp` is between a `start_time` and `end_time`, for all the days in the dataframe? Basically the same role of `.between_time()` but here the `timestamp` column can't be the index since there are repeated values.
Also, this is actually a chunk from `pd.read_csv()` and I would have to do this for several millions of them, would it be faster if I used for example `numpy` datetime functionalities? I guess I could create from `timestamp` a `time` column and create a mask on that, but I'm afraid this would be too slow.

EDIT:
I added more rows and this is the expected result, say for `start_time=datetime.time(18)`, `end_time=datetime.time(19)`:

```
                    timestamp  mes
0     2019-01-01 18:15:55.700  1228
1     2019-01-01 18:35:56.872  1402
2     2019-01-01 18:35:56.872  1560
5     2019-01-02 18:01:00.025  4124
6     2019-01-02 18:17:56.125  9736
7     2019-01-02 18:58:59.799  1597
```

My code (works but is slow):

```
df['time'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.time())
mask = (df.time<end) & (df.time>=start)
selected = df.loc[mask]
```

Comment: read_csv support's ```parse_dates``` attribute u can use that to convert to datetime object on load then apply filter's.

Comment: Include your code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: kindly post some more rows with expected output

Comment: added code and output!

Answer (score 0):

If you have you columns set to date time:

`start = df["timestamp"] >= "2019-01-01 18:15:55.700"
 end = df["timestamp"] <= "2019-01-01 18:15:55.896 "
 between_two_dates = start & end
 df.loc[between_two_dates]`

Comment: this wouldn't work because I need it for different days: 2019-01-01, 2019-01-02 etc

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Just set timestamp to datetime and take to index

```
  df=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2019-01-01 18:15:55.700','2019-01-01 18:17:55.700','2019-01-01 18:19:55.896'],'mes':[1228,1402,1560]})#Data
    df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])#Coerce timestamp to datetime
    df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)#set timestamp as index
    df.between_time('18:16', '20:15')#Time btetween select
```

Result

[image]

Comment: this wouldn't work as the values in 'timestamp' are not unique

Comment: Nope, timestamp/datetime doesnt work like that. Can you include the duplicate dates you are worried about in your query and let us know what output you expect?

Comment: added more rows and the expected output!